# $http.get() loops with ngrepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-http

I have 2 entities as below

```
person {
  personID,
  personName,
  Array of Cars (Person Car)
}

Cars {
  carID,
  carName
}
```

And then the relational entity for Person-Car as below

```
PersonCar {
  personID,
  CarID,
  relatedProperty1,
  relatedProperty2
}
```

Now, to represent this on data on a HTML page, I'm doing the below

```
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="person in persons">
       <div class="col-xs-6">
          {{person.personID}} - {{person.personName}}
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-12" ng-repeat="car in cars">
                {{person.carID}} - {{getCarName(person.carID)}} - 
              {{person.relatedProperty1}} - {{person.relatedProperty2}}
             </div>
             <!-- Each Car-->
          </div>
          <!-- Array of Cars-->
       </div>
       <!-- Array of Cars Section -->
    </div>
    <!-- Person Row-->
```

Further, the data is being retrieved as below

```
modelInfo.controller('modelInfoController', function ($scope, $http, $filter) {
    $http.get('http://localhost/person/123').
            success(function(data) {
              $scope.persons = data
            }

            $scope.getCarName = function(carID) {
            $http.get('http://localhost/car/54545').
                    success(function(data) {
                        $scope.persons = data.carName
            }                  
            }

            };
```

For some unknown reason, the script loops infinitely over the `getCarName` function. Please help me understand the issue. Also, please let me know if this is a good REST architecture.

Comment: This is a good spaguetti code. I believe you should solve it yourself. Analyze what you did and try to find what's wrong!! At the end of the day, SO isn't a mind fixing site at all...

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a couple closing parenthesizes

```
modelInfo.controller('modelInfoController', function ($scope, $http, $filter) {
    $http.get('http://localhost/person/123').success(
        function(data) {
          $scope.persons = data
        }
    ); // <-- here, closing success function call

    $scope.getCarName = function(carID) {
        $http.get('http://localhost/car/54545').success(
            function(data) {
                $scope.persons = data.carName;
            }
        ); // <-- here too       
    };

}); // <-- and here, closing the controller call
```

As for REST, it depends on how your backend server endpoints are defined

Although on the client side, you could define services for your resources, i.e. a wrapper for $http with REST methods (get, put, delete, update)